# AJAX .load lagging after multiple calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, crash, load, lag

So basically, I have a very simple HTML/JS page with some clickable book covers (.booklink). When you click on one of the covers, a description of the book is loaded in a div (#book).

```
$(".booklink").on("click", function(){
    $("#book").load('parts/' + $(this).attr("name") + '.html');
});
```

Now at first this works perfectly, but after clicking a few times, it starts lagging. After about 10 clicks my browser even crashes completely.

I've tried using .empty() before calling the .load, but I still get the same result.

Is there anything I can do about this? Am I doing something wrong? Is this just how AJAX works?

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:**

JSFiddle of main page: http://jsfiddle.net/Aqeav/

JSFiddle of one of the loaded pages: http://jsfiddle.net/nXGfq/

Comment: What are the contents of the files you are loading? I hope they are not complete html documents, with head elements and so on. For example, if there is a script in the document you are loading, it will execute. That could cause real havoc, depending on the script.

Comment: Could you show us a sample JSFiddle or demo implementation somewhere? We are missing the bigger picture here.

Comment: @Jeffman You might be on to something here. The documents aren't entire html documents. Just text with <h1> and <p> tags etc. However, they do all have a bit of external JS which automatically generates footnotes and adds links (<a href=#note1>[1]</a> etc.) to these notes in the text to every <sup class="note-ref" />. Do you think this might be the problem? If so, how can I fix it? I want to use JS on the loaded files but including the JS files on the main page doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta I'm not sure how to use multiple files and .load in JSFiddle as I'm not really familiar with that site. See my previous comment for more info. I don't think there's much else I can tell you, it's a pretty simple page.

Comment: I get your point. But what I would like to know is what exact content does your included HTML have? Could you include it into the question as a `code`?

Comment: @SunnyRGupta I made JSFiddles for the main page and one of the loaded pages. They're added to the question.